# Receiving emails on a Google domains subdomain

Tags: subdomain, email, mx, google-domains

I purchased a domain from Google Domains, say, `mydomain.tld`. I do not plan to have any hosting/content on this domain as of now. I'm not using any external services or providers, just Google Domains and GMail.

I added the alias `hello` to my email forwarding settings in Google Domains. Now, any emails sent to `hello@mydomain.tld` get forwarded to my own GMail address.

Instead, I would like to use a subdomain for my alias, such as `hello@abc.mydomain.tld` (note the extra `abc` subdomain).

I originally had MX records for the base domain, so I cloned them to the subdomain as well.

Original record:

```
domain.tld  MX  1 hour  
5 gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
10 alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
20 alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
30 alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
40 alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Cloned record:

```
abc.domain.tld  MX  1 hour  
5 gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
10 alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
20 alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
30 alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
40 alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

I do see this error message on intoDNS.com - are those related?

```
Error   Reverse MX A records (PTR)  ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are:
14.9.251.142.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
14.157.250.142.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
14.150.250.142.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips
```



If not, what am I missing? How do I get email forwarding working with my subdomain?

Comment: From ServerFault: [Create MX Record for Subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/870845/create-mx-record-for-subdomain) and [MX Record for SubDomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/374974/mx-record-for-subdomains)

Comment: You can create a new MX record for `abc.mydomain.tld` and point the record to your server (you can refer to `mydomain.tld`'s record).

Comment: @CHOOYJ that's what I figured. I cloned the entries from the original MX record for the domain, as an entry for the subdomain. Doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @CHOOYJ updated my question to add relevant details

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I do have MX records for the subdomain, cloned from the original record. See updated question.

Comment: @metacubed Did you set up forwarding for your subdomain?

Comment: @CHOOYJ I don't have any content on my domain or my subdomain. There's nothing to forward _to_, right?

Comment: @metacubed Sorry, it is email forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

My observation, as a web host who sets up google workspace for many customers, is that intoDNS always returns that error for anyone using google servers for their MX records

Here's an example...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @Steve. I'm still not receiving any emails on my subdomain, though.

Comment: Do you have an A record for the subdomain?

Comment: I don't, there's no content hosted on the site, so there's no IP address to point at.